# gksu texteditor changes rights from user to root after save

Tags: debian, pam

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)
Release:    9.1
Codename:   stretch
```

whenever I use mousepad or another editor calling with gksu form terminal and save the changed file it breaks the permission to `/run/user/1000/dconf/user`
 and the Prozeß `mate-settings-daemon`
 slows the system of course . `systemd --version
systemd 232
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN`
 
libpam-systemd-version `LANG=C apt-cache policy libpam-systemd
libpam-systemd:
  Installed: 232-25+deb9u1
  Candidate: 232-25+deb9u1
  Version table:
 *** 232-25+deb9u1 500
        500 http://http.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

In journal during cmd.

```
Aug 17 10:01:42 Taomon su[6755]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by alex(uid=1000)
Aug 17 10:01:42 Taomon su[6755]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
```

I always use gksu for graphical programms, but gksu acts like I would only call su.

`
No sudo in use. Editor like nano are working fine.

Any hints, where to look?

Same effekt wenn I stroke ALT+F2 and run gksu every program from there. Something wrong with gksu.

```
LANG=C update-alternatives --display libgksu-gconf-defaults 
libgksu-gconf-defaults - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/share/libgksu/debian/gconf-defaults.libgksu-su
  link currently points to /usr/share/libgksu/debian/gconf-defaults.libgksu-su
  link libgksu-gconf-defaults is /usr/share/gconf/defaults/10_libgksu
/usr/share/libgksu/debian/gconf-defaults.libgksu-su - priority 20
/usr/share/libgksu/debian/gconf-defaults.libgksu-sudo - priority 10
```

Comment: Why are you using `gksu` to start the editor if you’re editing files which belong to your user? You’re running the editor as `root`, you should expect problems such as those you’re seeing...

Comment: I use the Editor for system-files not for my usual user's one. I need the search funktion in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using gksu -l. It will treat it as a login shell, resetting your environment to the default for the target user (root). Right now the editor is seeing your user's environment, including config location, but using it as root.

Note that you may have to deal with Xauthority stuff - this information is part of your environment. If this is a single-user system, just `sudo ln -s /home/[your user]/.Xauthority /root/` to give root persistent access to any X server started by you. You also may need to provide `$DISPLAY`, but gksu might do that for you.

Comment: This works. `gksu -l`.

Comment: @Bahamut Thank you very much for your bounty!